# MarkLogic Search Suggest with Java API

Tags: java, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to implement a search suggest for the app I am building. I tried following the guide [found here](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_45754).

I modified things a bit to work with my database. My options now look like this:

```
String options =
        <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
            <default-suggestion-source>
                <range type="xs:string" facet="true">" +
                    <element ns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" name="content"/>
                </range>
            </default-suggestion-source>
        </options>;
```

The name "content" is the name of the XML element I want to search, and the namespace I wasn't sure about, so I just copied the namespace that was in the default range indexes already in my database.

My Index looks like this:
[image: range element index]

My Java code is as follows:

```
StringHandle handle = new StringHandle(options);
QueryManager queryManager = client.newQueryManager();
QueryOptionsManager optMgr = client.newServerConfigManager().newQueryOptionsManager();
optMgr.writeOptions("opt-suggest", handle);

SuggestDefinition suggestionDef = queryManager.newSuggestDefinition();
suggestionDef.setLimit(10);
suggestionDef.setStringCriteria(text);
suggestionDef.setOptionsName("opt-suggest");
String[] suggestions = queryManager.suggest(suggestionDef);
```

The line setting the options name to the suggestion def I added as it was not in the tutorial.
The search returns an empty set every time. Is it because of my namespace? Or am I missing something? FWIW I have tried running it with the namespace shown, and with a blank namespace.

**Edit:** Sample document:

```
<Article doctype="article>
    <title>Some Name here</title>
    <content>
        <content type="paragraph">
            <value>Some text</value>
        </content>
        <content type="paragraph">
            <value>More text</value>
        </content>
    </content>
</Article
```

Comment: please add a sample XML document that you expect to give suggestions from

Comment: Added a sample doc. Now that I look at it, is the issue that im searching on the 'content' element instead of the 'value' element?

Edit: Nvm, changed 'content' to 'value' and still nothing

Comment: It sure sounds like you have a namespace issue, even though your Sample document doesn't show any namespace.  Remember to make sure you have a blank namespace in both the options and the Range Index.  You can test directly against the range index by running the following Javascript in QConsole: `cts.elementValueMatch(xs.QName("value"), "*")`

Comment: Did you try changing 'content' to 'value' and getting rid of the namespace?

Comment: Yes, removed the namespace and still nothing. I ran the Javscript you gave me in the console and it returns values, so the Index is working.

Edit: When I replace the * with a value it returns nothing. I assume the star would be the value entered in a search bar? Sorry, i'm still very new with MarkLogic.

Comment: I would take the java layer out of it all together and do your testing in query console using search:suggest() and your options. Once it is all tuned and working, then worry about inetgration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works! Sam Mefford's comment about running in the console made me realize it would in fact return results, just not for my search string. I threw some wildcards around the search text and it now works; after adjusting my index and options to search the proper XML element, and leaving the namespace blank.

Comment: Since you found the answer, please mark this as "Accepted" so that others know the question has been addressed.

Comment: It won't let me accept it until tomorrow, but I will do it as soon as I am able.